# How to drag map but keep marker to center vue2Leaflet map?

Tags: vue.js, vue2leaflet

leaflet map on my project. My marker is set to center map using lat and lng. Now I want, whenever a user will drag or move map, marker should be in center (fixed) and can get lat and lng marker.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you show us some code, but I think you should have something similar to this to make marker snap to the center of the map:

```js
 let marker = L.marker(myMap.getCenter(), { icon: hyperMarker }).addTo(myMap)
```

Now you can use this method make the marker snap to the center of the map whenever `move` event happens:

```js
  myMap.on('move', (event) => {
      marker.setLatLng(myMap.getCenter())
      this.markerLatLang = marker.getLatLng()
    })
```